# "illegal generic type of instanceof" when using instanceof on an inner class type?

Tags: java, inner-classes, instanceof

I coded in NetBeans something like this:

```
public class Grafo<V, E>
{
    class Par
    {
        int a, b;
        Par(int a, int b) {
            this.a = a;
            this.b = b;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean equals(Object ob)
        {
            if(ob instanceof Par) {
                Par p = (Par)ob;
                return this.a==p.a && this.b==p.b;
            }

            return false;
        }
    }

    //stuff...
} //end of class Grafo
```

The error is in the method equals() from inner class "Par".

NetBeans says that the error is "illegal generic type of instanceof". The error is in the line below.

```
            if(ob instanceof Par) {
```

What is the cause of the error ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try `ob instanceof Grafo<?,?>.Par`

I think that the compiler thinks that `ob instanceof Par` involves a runtime check on generic type parameters; i.e. that it is equivalent to `ob instanceof Grafo<V,E>.Par`.  But `instanceof` tests cannot check generic type parameters.

Answer (score 4):

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
@Override
public boolean equals(Object ob)
{
    if(ob instanceof Grafo.Par) {
        Par p = (Par)ob;
        return this.a==p.a && this.b==p.b;
    }

    return false;
}
```

Or define your inner class `static`