# Error "illegal generic type for instanceof" when using local classes

Tags: java, generics, local-class

I have the following Java code that uses a *local class*.

```java
import java.util.Arrays;

public class X<T> {
    void m() {
        class Z {}

        for (Object o : Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3))
            if (o instanceof Z) {}
    }
}
```

It does not compile with the following error message:

```
X.java:8: error: illegal generic type for instanceof
            if (o instanceof Z) {}
                             ^
1 error
```

I understand that the local class `Z` inherits the generic type signature of `X<T>`, being an inner class. The same kind of compilation error appears in this example, where `Z` is not local, but still inner:

```java
import java.util.Arrays;

public class X<T> {
    class Z {}

    void m() {
        for (Object o : Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3))
            if (o instanceof Z) {} // Compilation error
    }
}
```

It can be worked around either by making `Z` non-inner / static:

```java
import java.util.Arrays;

public class X<T> {
    static class Z {}

    void m() {
        for (Object o : Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3))
            if (o instanceof Z) {} // Compiles now
    }
}
```

Or by [qualifying `X.Z`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1895696/521799):

```java
import java.util.Arrays;

public class X<T> {
    class Z {}

    void m() {
        for (Object o : Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3)) {
            if (o instanceof X.Z) {}    // Compiles now
            if (o instanceof X<?>.Z) {} // Also
        }
    }
}
```

But how can I qualify a local class, or work around this limitation, without changing the local class itself?

Comment: I think this is a kind of compiler pathology. It's a strange way of telling you the type is not reifiable. It's even worse in Eclipse - it tells you "Use the form Z instead".

Comment: @RealSkeptic: Eclipse's compiler message is just "unlucky" here. It is usually a helpful extra information.

Comment: A  corollary of this is that `Z[] array = new Z[0];` is also illegal.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

To me this seems to be an oversight or limitation in the Java language and I do not think it is possible.

The referenced type in an `instanceof` expression must be reifiable according to [JLS 4.7](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se9/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.7), meaning that it must be expressed as a reifiable type by its fully qualified name. At the same time, [JLS 6.7](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-6.html#jls-6.7) states that local classes do not have a fully qualified name, they can therefore not be expressed as reifiable.

If you declare Z as generic, the `instanceof` operator treats `Z` as a raw type where all generic properties to it - in this case the enclosing class - are considered raw as well. (Similar to a generic methods of a raw type being considered as raw despite any generic signature. This is a measure to retain backwards compatiblity of type generification.) Since any raw type is reifiable, declaring Z to be generic will compile.

Comment: It's true, but curiously, it does allow it if `Z` itself is generic, despite the fact that you have no way to qualify it.

Comment: *"oversight"* - You're here to pick a fight with the JLS designers, right? :)

Comment: Generics were patched into the language and there are some corner cases such as class literals that were not properly covered. Nothing is perfect, I think there is a chance for an oversight. ;)

Comment: I extended my answer to explain why generification of `Z` does the trick.

Comment: @LukasEder I think oversight is right. It's sort of like [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50633759/how-to-refer-to-a-class-when-both-simple-and-fully-qualified-names-clash): these cases could have been designed around, but they haven't been; I make no judgment as to whether they *should* have been.

Comment: @AndyTurner: What I mean by "maybe not oversight" is that someone may have thought of it, but explicitly decided to not specify it for various reasons, including insufficient cost/benefit ratio. In fact, just like your linked example, which could be solved by type aliasing and partial imports, such as in Scala, but it may have been decided not to solve this problem (yet).

Answer (score 28):

A possible workaround is to use reflection:

```java
import java.util.Arrays;

public class X<T> {
    void m() {
        class Z {}

        for (Object o : Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3))
            if (Z.class.isInstance(o)) {}
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Apparently, by making Z generic compilation succeeds. I expected that to require `<T>` as the type parameter, but you just have to make it generic, so anything will do

```java
import java.util.Arrays;

public class X<T> {
    void m() {
        class Z<Anything> {}

        for (Object o : Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3))
            if (Z.class.isInstance(o)) {}
    }
}
```

Proper solution would be qualify the local class, but I don't think you can. Either you refactor it to a private static class or that's probably the best you can get.

Comment: Once you make `Z` generic, you don't need to apply the reflection workaround anymore...

Answer (score 3):

This should work either. Using reflection too. But seems a valid solution.

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class X<T> {


    void m() {

        class Z2 {
        }

        for(Object o: Arrays.asList(1,2,3)) {
            if(Z2.class.isAssignableFrom(o.getClass())) {

            }
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: I didn't downvote, but I guess it's because there's a slightly better way to use reflection here, as I've mentioned [in my own answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55703850/521799)